# How can i access google calendar informations?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an application in Android where i require the all my agends from google calendar? Can anyone help me how can i acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this ll help you..

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html